# Ninject.Web (webforms extension), injecting outside of a webform page?

Tags: asp.net, inversion-of-control, ninject, ninject.web

I've been using the Ninject.Web extension to inject business objects, repositories, Entity Framework context etc into my application.  This works very well using the [Inject] attribute which can be applied within a webform that inherits from PageBase.  I am now running into a snag as I am trying to write a custom membership provider that needs injection done inside of it but of course this provider is not instantiated from within a webform.  Forms Authentication will instantiate the object when it needs it.  I am unsure how to about doing this without having access to the [Inject] attribute.  I understand that there is an application level kernel somewhere, but I have no idea how to tap into it.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.  I just went through all my previous questions and made sure to accept those that where the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do a `IKernel.Inject` on the the instance. Have a look at the source for the Application class in the extension project you're using.

In the case of V2, [it's in a `KernelContainer`](http://github.com/ninject/ninject.web/blob/master/source/Ninject.Web/KernelContainer.cs). So you need to do a:

```
KernelContainer.Inject( this )
```

where `this` is the non-page, non application class of which you speak.

You'll need to make sure this only happens once - be careful doing this in `Global`, which may get instantiated multiple times.

Also, your Application / `Global` class needs to derive from [NinjectHttpAppplication](http://github.com/ninject/ninject.web/blob/master/source/Ninject.Web/NinjectHttpApplication.cs), but I'm sure you've that covered.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to use the service locator pattern, just inject into properties of your custom membership provider in Application_Start. Assuming you've registed the providers properly you can do this with something like:

```
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

        RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);

        // Inject account repository into our custom membership & role providers.
        _kernel.Inject(Membership.Provider);

        // Register the Object Id binder.
        ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(ObjectId), new ObjectIdModelBinder()); 
    }
```

I've written up a more in depth explanation here:

http://www.danharman.net/2011/06/23/asp-net-mvc-3-custom-membership-provider-with-repository-injection/

Answer (score 0):

you may need to use the [Service Locator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648968.aspx) pattern, since you have no control over the creation of the membership provider.

Comment: I would like to stay away from a true Service Locator at this point.  At this point I am thinking that the Ninject.Web while nice doesn't really do it for me since I need to be able to inject in webforms as well as in other places.  I am considering a static instance via a singleton at this point.

Comment: -1: SL pattern still takes control of the creation - post-injection or whatever it's correctly termed is what's wanted